# Generar Código en Android Studio mediante atajos del teclado

Tags: android-studio, atajo

Buenas, estoy comenzando con Android Studio y me surge la siguiente duda de novato .Quiero generar código a través del atajo Alt + inserte  pero a la hora de seleccionar generar constructor no me permite seleccionar todos los atributos de la clase , solo puedo seleccionar de uno en uno y generarlos individualmente ( con la consiguiente perdida de tiempo).

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

[image: AndroidStudio]

Comment: puedes mantener shift y hacer hacia abajo con las flechas, o marcarlos con clic mientras mantienes presionado ctrl, no funciona?

Comment: presionando ctrl funciona :) muchas gracias.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo agrega tu respuesta, sería de ayuda para otros usuarios de Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes presionar las teclas `shift` y moverte hacia arriba o abajo usando las flechas direccionales para marcarlos, o en su defecto, presionando la tecla `ctrl` y haciendo `clic` en los elementos que desees elegir.